# How to execute TCL commands of Rocket Universe through Ansible?

Tags: c#, .net, universe

I wanna execute 3-4 commands of Universe(which is in Linux) by executing some program through Ansible in Windows. I was having a look at UniObjects but couldn't find it how to add it in C# console app and not sure if it is free of cost. The aim is automation as I want to execute those commands(COPY, BASIC, RUN) without any user interaction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add an example of the code you want to run in UniVerse and I maybe of some help. You state that you don't want user interaction, but do you want to fire and forget this code and assume success or do you want more of handshake?

Comment: @VanAmburg
These are the steps which I wanna accomplish (maybe through .NET Core app or shell script in Linux and then execute it through Ansible):

- First step is that I wanna login to UniVerse by giving it username and password and then entering the account name.

- Second step is that I wanna **STOP.PHANTOMS**

- Third step is that I wanna execute the command **COPY SRC.FILE SOME.PROGRAM (O
TO: (DEST.FILE**

- Fourth step is that I want to compile and run SOME.PROGRAM by using the commands: **BASIC DEST.FILE SOME.PROGRAM** and **RUN DEST.FILE SOME.PROGRAM**

Comment: @VanAmburg
Isn't there any way I could login to Universe and execute these TCL commands using Linux terminal commands ? Because if that is possible then I can run those Linux commands through Ansible directly.

Comment: That is the angle I would go. Will post example...

Comment: Note: Rocket Universe doesn't support .NET Core with the current version of the MVTools (as of Dec 2018), only .NET Framework is supported. That might be a big issue with Ansible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the user that is running the script has permissions to everything you need to do and that your shell doesn't jump straight into a menu when it starts Universe, it is easy to run UV code from the the OS shell. In the Unix/Linux world it is common practice to use this sort of strategy to execute processes from cron. You might check to see if you have examples there to maintain standards.

In my shop we generally collect them into a single PA entry in the VOC and then PHANTOM that off when we want to run it. I don't know what STOP.PHANTOMS does (I assume that is a local thing) but here is a mock example that expects that it will not to kill the phantom we just spawned off to run this.

```
>ED VOC COPY.FOOBAR
5 lines long.

----: p
0001: PA
0002: STOP.PHANTOMS
0003: COPY FROM FOO TO BAR FOOBAR OVERWRITING
0004: BASIC BAR FOOBAR
0005: RUN BAR FOOBAR
```

and the shell script

```
cd /path/to/account
/path/to/uv/bin/uv <<start
PHANTOM COPY.FOOBAR
start
```

You can probably do it without using PHANTOM as well, though I have not really experimented with it much.